# Using WebBrowser to print documents in a listbox

Tags: c#, .net, printing, webbrowser-control

Essentially, I'd like my program to load a list into a `ListBox`, and allow the user to click "Print", which navigates the `WebBrowser` to each page in the list, printing them all out individually.

However, it's only printing out 2 pages (in my example I have 4 pages in the listbox) and then stops, not completing the loop. (Most likely due to the `WebBrowser` control still being busy)

I feel like I'm making a simple mistake here. Any insight as to what is causing this is greatly appreciated!

My code:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DirSearch(Application.StartupPath);
}

void DirSearch(string sDir)
{
    try
    {
        foreach (string d in Directory.GetDirectories(sDir))
        {
            foreach (string f in Directory.GetFiles(d).Select(Path.GetFileName))
            {
                listBox1.Items.Add(f);
            }
            DirSearch(d);
        }
    }
    catch (System.Exception excpt)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(excpt.Message);
    }
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    WebBrowser webBrowserForPrinting = new WebBrowser();
    webBrowserForPrinting.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(PrintDocument);

    foreach (string s in listBox1.Items)
    {
        try
        {
            webBrowserForPrinting.Url = new Uri(Application.StartupPath + "\\COAForms\\" + s);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
        }
    }
}

private void PrintDocument(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    // Print the document now that it is fully loaded.
    ((WebBrowser)sender).Print();

}
```

Comment: The code looks good though you should put a message in that empty catch - I think you're probably suppressing the error which would probably shed light on the problem.

Answer (score 0):

A common mistake with the web browser control is to try to use it in a traditional `for` loop, like you have here.

WebBrowser page loading is an asynchronous action.  That is why there is a DocumentCompleted event.  You need to account for this in your loop.  Have the DocumentCompleted (eg. `PrintDocument`) handler load the next location instead of using a traditional for loop.